# Как авторизоваться в instagram?

Tags: c#, авторизация, аутентификация

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь авторизоваться в инстаграме программным путём, вот что делаю:

```
CookieDictionary cook = new CookieDictionary();

string Get()
{
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.Cookies = cook;
    //отправляем запрос
    HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/");
    // Принимаем тело сообщения в виде строки
    string content = response.ToString();
    string pattern = @"([0-9a-f]{32})";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(content); 

    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}

void Auth()
{
    try
    {
        string tok = Get();
        var request = new HttpRequest();
        request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.FirefoxUserAgent();
        request.Cookies = cook;
        request.AddParam("username", "логин");
        request.AddParam("password", "пароль");
        request.AddParam("csrf_token", tok);

        HttpResponse response = request.Post("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/");
        /*if (response.Cookies.TryGetValue("csrfmiddlewaretoken", out tok))
            return true;
         return false;*/
    }
```

Выдаёт код ошибки 403. может у кого есть примеры авторизации через api?
Работаю тут с библиотекой xNet. Документацию инсты читал, но примеров на шарп у них нет.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что всё это имеет хоть какое-то отношение к Instagram API?

Comment: это не имеет отношения к апи. я сказал что такой способ не работает, поэтому спрашиваю, есть ли у кого-то способы авторизации через апи

Comment: Конесно есть. И они выкликиваются за долю секунды там, где и должны быть: на сайте инстаграма, под словом "API".

Comment: в апи инстаграмма нет аутентификации по имени пользователя и пароля. есть только oauth, который требует редиректа на сайт инстаграмма. пропускать имя и пароль пользователя через стороннее приложение - небезопасно, так что не ждите простого и удобного способа это сделать.

Comment: Так этот токен получается один раз и работает долго. Мои, например, уже больше года живут.

Comment: @klopp можете скинуть пример того как вы авторизовались?

Comment: Да как там и сказано :) Сначала регистрируем клиента, потом ловим токен как написано здесь: https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/  , первый же пункт "Server-side (Explicit) Flow".

Comment: а в "WEBSITE URL" и "REDIRECT URI" какие сайты указывать надо?

Comment: Художественное чтение вслух документации - спецпрайс.

Comment: прекрасный ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ничего особо сложного в аутентификации через форму нет. Можно даже не разбирать страницу, а брать csrf-токен из cookies.

Класс используемый для аутентификации:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InstagramClient
{
    public class Instagram : IDisposable
    {
        private const string USER_AGENT = 
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) "+
            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "+
            "Chrome/45.0.2414.0 Safari/537.36";

        private HttpClientHandler m_handler;
        private HttpClient m_client;

        /// <summary>
        /// Http-клиент, который после аунтификации
        /// можно использовать для выполнения 
        /// различных действий на сайте .
        /// </summary>
        public HttpClient Client
        {
            get { return m_client; }
        }

        public Instagram()
        {
            m_handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            m_client = new HttpClient(m_handler);
            m_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://instagram.com/");
            m_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(USER_AGENT);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_client.Dispose();
            m_handler.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Осуществляет вход в Instagram,
        /// аналогично использованию стандартной формы логина в браузере
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Логин либо e-mail</param>
        /// <param name="password">Пароль</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            // получаем страницу входа, что бы сайт установил Cookie 'csrftoken'
            // содержимое страницы нам не важно
            await m_client.GetAsync("/accounts/login/");

            // получаем токен из Cookies
            var cookies = m_handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(m_client.BaseAddress);
            var csrftoken = cookies["csrftoken"].Value;

            // готовим поля для формы входа
            var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "username", username },
                { "password", password }
            };

            // готовим запрос
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/accounts/login/ajax/");
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields);

            request.Headers.Referrer = new Uri(m_client.BaseAddress, "/accounts/login/");

            // Дополнительные заголовки запроса.
            // Кроме X-CSRFToken, остальное в общем-то не обязательно.
            request.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Instagram-AJAX", "1");
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

            // Авторзуемся через AJAX
            var response = await m_client.SendAsync(request);
            var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginInfo>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            return info.authenticated;
        }

        private class LoginInfo
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public bool authenticated { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и в случае успешной аунтификации, используем Client для получения/отправки нужной нам информации:

```
using (var instagram = new Instagram())
{
    if (await instagram.LoginAsync("User", "Pa$$word"))
    {
        var homepage = await instagram.Client.GetStringAsync("/");

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Ну а по поводу API:

1. [регистрируетесь сами](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/)
2. [регистрируете нового клиента](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/) (там же указываете redirect-uri)
3. смотрите в документации, и вызываете методы которые вам необходимы

Redirect-uri при авторизации сайтов равен обработчику на сервере. При авторизации приложений может быть равен в общем-то практически чему угодно(даже не существующему, если у вас есть контроль над запросами клиента), главное что вы могли вытащить ACCESS-TOKEN из URL на который вас instagram переадресует.

Comment: сергей, скажите сейчас код актуальный? или инстаграм добавил дополнительную проверку? ps у меня код не работает, хотя по внешнему виду правильный.

Comment: @hitcode, уже нет. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486617/17298 - здесь более актуальный. Сейчас проверил - код из того ответа вполне рабочий.

Comment: спасибо Серег, а то чё то никто не поможет товарищам программистам. =)