# Авторизация в instagram без API

Tags: c#

Как авторизироваться в instagram.com без API через GET запросы с помощью C# и сохранением куков? Можно рабочий пример?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Как авторизоваться в instagram?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428051/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-instagram)

Comment: А почему, пардон, без API, если есть API?

Comment: Через API есть много ограничений, потому хочеться попробовать чтото новое и где нет таких ограничений как в API.

Comment: @Mikhail121: Думаете, ограничения на сайте менее существенны? Они ж не просто так выставлены, чтобы позлить программистов.

Comment: есть задача сделать такую вещь. Потому прошу у Вас совета и части рабочего кода.

Comment: @Mikhail121, в [ответе на указанный мною выше вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428173/17298) есть полностью рабочий код.

Comment: Не работает строка JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginInfo>...

Comment: @Mikhail121, что значит "не работает"? Как минимум должна выдаваться какая то ошибка, поясняющая **почему** не работает.

Comment: Компилятор вернул следующюю ошибку: Внедрение типов взаимодействия из сборки "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" невозможно, так как у нее отсутствует атрибут "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute" или атрибут "System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute"