# C# + cUrl авторизаци в instagram без API

Tags: c#, curl, cmd, instagram

Есть задача связать cUrl и C# и сделать авторизацию для instagram. 
Создаю динамически *.bat файлы и запускаю их в консоле, но немогу залогиниться на сайте. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
string batnik = "curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt";
        batnik += " \"https://www.instagram.com/\"";
        batnik += " -D header.txt";
        batnik += " -H \"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\" ";
        batnik += " -H \"accept-language: uk,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Cookie: csrftoken = " + Token + "; s_network=; ig_pr=1; ig_vw=1280;  mid = " + this.mid + "\"";
        batnik += " -H \"upgrade-insecure-requests: 1\"";
        batnik += " -H \"User - Agent: " + UserAgent + "\"";
        batnik += " -H \"accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*; q = 0.8\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Referer: https://www.instagram.com/\"";
        batnik += " -H \"cache-control: max-age=0 \"";
        batnik += " -H \"authority: www.instagram.com\"";
        batnik += " --compressed >> " + user + "-first.txt";

        File.WriteAllText(user + "-first.bat", batnik);
        Process.Start("cmd", " /C  " + user + "-first.bat");
```

После этого создаю и запускаю следующий *.bat файл.

```
string batnik = "curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt";
        batnik += " \"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/\"";
        batnik += "  -D header.txt";
        batnik += " -H \"Cookie: csrftoken = " + Token + "; mid = " + this.mid + ";\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Origin: https://www.instagram.com\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Accept - Encoding: gzip, deflate\"";
        batnik += " -H \"accept-language: uk,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\"";
        batnik += " -H \" user-agent: " + UserAgent + "\"";
        batnik += " -H \"x - requested - with: XMLHttpRequest\" ";
        batnik += " -H \"X - CSRFToken: " + Token + "\"";
        batnik += " -H \"X - Instagram - AJAX: 1\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Content - Type: application / x - www - form - urlencoded; charset = UTF - 8\"";
        batnik += " -H \"Accept: */*\" -H \"Referer: https://www.instagram.com/\"";
        batnik += " -H \"authority: www.instagram.com\" ";
        batnik += " --data \"username = " + user + " & password = " + pass + "\" --compressed >> " + user + "-login.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(user + "-login.bat", batnik);
            Process.Start("cmd", " /C  " + user + "-login.bat");
```

Пока вот так, но все равно немогу залогиниться.
Помогите кто чем может.
P.S. PHP не предлагать, уже есть рабочий вариант, нужно именно C# + cUrl.

Answer (score 6):

Может проще без CURL'а? :)

Практически то же самое, что и у вас, только с использованием [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

1. Создаём экземпляр клиента, добавляем контейнер для Cookies, присваиваем из константы любимый User Agent:

   ```
   var client = new RestClient("https://www.instagram.com/");

   client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   client.UserAgent = USER_AGENT;
   ```
2. Делаем первый запрос, цель которого - получить csrf-токен из Cookies:

   ```
   var firstRequest = new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);
   var firstResponse = client.Execute(firstRequest);

   var csrftoken = firstResponse.Cookies.First(x => x.Name == "csrftoken").Value;
   ```
3. Отправляем логин/пароль, а в ответ получаем JSON со статусом:

   ```
   var loginRequest = new RestRequest("/accounts/login/ajax/", Method.POST);
   loginRequest.AddHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
   loginRequest.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
   loginRequest.AddHeader("X-Instagram-AJAX", "1");
   loginRequest.AddHeader("Referer", client.BaseUrl.ToString());
   loginRequest.AddParameter("username", username);
   loginRequest.AddParameter("password", password);

   var loginResponse = client.Execute<LoginResponse>(loginRequest).Data;
   ```

   Класс `LoginResponse`, используемый для десериализации и хранения ответа сервера:

   ```
   public class LoginResponse
   {
       public string status { get; set; }
       public bool authenticated { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Ура! `loginResponse.authenticated` равно `True` -  Пользователь аутентифицировался! Можем продолжать делать какие-то запросы из под этого пользователя к инстаграму, используя наш `client`.

Comment: Добрый день! А не приведёте, пожалуйста, пример, как теперь сделать запрос из-под этого пользователя? Вот такой код:

 var selfRequest = new RestRequest("/users/self", Method.GET);
 var selfResponse = client.Execute(selfRequest);

не работает, возвращает статус "Not found".

Comment: Просто лучший, объяснили все понятно сразу стало!